# Fixing svn UTF-8 data issues in hgsubversion pull

Tags: svn, mercurial, utf-8, pull, hgsubversion

I've encountered an error while pulling svn changes into my mercurial repo:

```
abort: ('Valid UTF-8 data\n(hex: 75 6c 6c 20 74 61 73 6b 20 6c 69 73 74 20 74 68 65 20 63 6c 69 65 6e 74)\nfollowed by invalid UTF-8 sequence\n(hex: 92 73 20 4e)', 22)
```

I've found out [how to detect it for svn](http://arjuna.deltoso.net/articles/subversion-messy-encoding-valid-utf-8-data-followed-by-invalid-utf-8-sequence/) (with a fix for filenames, but not content); how do I apply this detection to hgsubversion so I can continue pulling??

Comment: I thought `convmv  -f latin1 -t utf-8 *` was the answer, but that only converts the file name

Answer (score 0):

The following does not work - see step 4 (upvote if this is **helpful** in saving you time :)). Hopefully the real answer is some variation on this...

1. Have a look at the svn log for the revision, and see what files are affected (hopefully a small amount)
2. for each file use `isutf8 .hg/store/data/trunk/{svn path}` (from `moreutils` package) (where [my] branches appear in the trunk as well due to hg branching stuff I don't understand...).
   If things are going "correctly wrong", then the offset that `isutf8` complains about should be very close to the `invalid UTF-8 sequence` message. In my case, `isutf8` complained at position 24, where my error was at 22 (I reckon this is just reporting either the start or the end of unicode decoding...)
3. Do something along the lines of

   ```
   iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 {file name} > {temp file}
   mv {file name} ~ # For backup purposes
   mv {temp file} {file name}
   ```
4. Watch as `hg pull` fails again after finally logging svn and starting pulling *after* I've written my optimistic answer.